# How do I use the integral function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to use the integral function to integrate the prior_probs function below.

```
M = 0;
V = 10;
prior_probs = @(x,V,M) (1/sqrt(2*pi*V))*exp((-1/(2*V))*((x-M)^2));
q = integral(@(x) prior_probs(x,V,M),-Inf,0);
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error using  ^  (line 51)
Incorrect dimensions for raising a matrix to a power. Check that the matrix is square and the power is a scalar.
To perform elementwise matrix powers, use '.^'.
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message actually tells you what the error is. You need to add `.^2` (see below) because the `integral` built-in function in Matlab uses vectors for the independent variable `x` to speed up computations.

```
prior_probs = @(x,V,M) (1/sqrt(2*pi*V))*exp((-1/(2*V))*((x-M).^2));
```

Now your code should work.